# How to change dynamically the @click method in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the need of changing the method that a button executed dynamically. In Javascript, it will be as easy as giving the button and id, for example `id="my-button"`, and then do

`document.getElementById("my-button").setAttribute("onclick", "theNewMethodToExecute()")`

And just like that, the button will execute the new method. How can I do that in Vue.js?

I have a simple mini-project to show my problem:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./ts/generated/logic.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="" id="app">
      <p class="">My number is:</p>
      <button @click="methodToExecute"></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.ts (I write my Vue app in TypeScript instead of JavaScript, and I use Webpack and npm to compile my result, which compiles to a file called `logic.js`)

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const myApp = new Vue({
    data() {
        return {
            methodToExecute: "doNothing",
        };
    },
    methods: {
        doNothing() {
            console.log("Dong nothing...")
            this.methodToExecute = "doSomethingElse"
        },
        doSomethingElse() {
            console.log("Doing something else...")
        },

    },
});

myApp.$mount("#app");
```

In this case I tried with a property but that not work.

Note: I am aware that I can conditionally change the method like this:

```
v-on="{click: condition ? doWhenTrue : doWhenFalse}"
```

But the logic I have is much more complex, and I need to change the method programatically, the way I can do in JavaScript, How is that possible with Vue?

Comment: Is there some particular reason you need to swap out the click handler instead of having the click handle make the decision of what to do? In other words, instead of trying to attach either `doWhenTrue` or `doWhenFalse` in your last example, just attach `doTheRightThing` and have `doTheRightThing` evaluate the condition and call the appropriate function then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you put the condition inside the method and pass an argument to it? I'm not sure on what you're trying to achieve but something like this would work for your use case.

```
<a @click="doNothingOrSomething(condition)"></a>

methods: {
    doNothingOrSomething(arg) {
        if (arg === 'something') {
            console.log("Doing nothing...")
        } else console.log("Doing something else...")
    }
}
```

Using that reasoning, the result will be:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const myApp = new Vue({
    data() {
        return {
            argument: "",
        };
    },
    methods: {
        doNothingOrSomething() {
            switch (this.argument) {
                case "method1": {
                    console.log("Is method 1")
                    this.argument = "method2"
                    break;
                }
                case "method2": {
                    console.log("Is method 2")
                    this.argument = "method3"
                    break;
                }
                case "method3": {
                    console.log("Is method 3")
                    this.argument = "method1"
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    console.log("default")
                    this.argument = "method1"
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    },
});

myApp.$mount("#app");
```

and the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./ts/generated/logic.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="" id="app">
      <p class="">My number is:</p>
      <button @click="doNothingOrSomething"></button>
    </div>
    <script></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And that makes it work dynamically!